# How to serve an image variable in a response?

Tags: django, python-3.x

When serving a file, we normally include it in the `Response` as such:

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attatchment; filename="<file-path>"'
```

My issue however is I need to serve an image file from a variable. The image is stored on a different server which is downloaded, stored as a variable, and then needs to be attached to my `Response` object. Is this possible? Something like the following:

```
import PIL, io
from django.http import HttpResponse
img = PIL.Image.open(io.BytesIO(photo_bytes))
response = HttpResponse(content-type='image/png')
response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attatchment; filebytes="{photobytes}"'
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! Apparently you can just write bytes to the response directly like so

```
response = HttpResponse(photo_bytes, content_type=f'image/png')
```